# Этимология фамилии Пешков

Tags: этимология, ономастика, фамилии

Объясните этимологию фамилии Пешков.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 1):

А я думаю,что этимология здесь неоднозначна, ведь фамилии образовывались и от крестильных имён, тогда Пешков  от  Пешко - как итог упрощения Пётр (русский диалект);

и от прозвищ, тогда возможно происхождение от пехать – «толкать, сдвигать от себя толчком, тычком, совать»; «заталкивать, всовывать, уминать, совать силой»- тот, кто пехает;

пешой, пеший – «кто не едет, идет на своих ногах, идет пешком»;

пешка – «о человеке маленького роста».

Таким образом, прозвище Пешко мог иметь человек, много путешествовавший пешком (странник), либо человек небольшого роста.

Горький вот воспротивился тому, чтобы его предок был "пешка"-маловажный человек, ему ближе "пешком".

Чья-то фамилия Пешков может восходить к названию деревни – Пешково (Алапаевский район), образованному от имени его основателя.

В общем, нужно искать основателя фамилии, предка - Пешко и знать, откуда его имя или прозвище.

Приведённые в словаре фамилии никак не могут образоваться одинаково:

В старинных архивных документах зафиксированы, например, Пан Пешко, в Галиции (1403); княже Андреев Меншего Семен Пешков Сабуров, воевода вологодский (1469); Васка Пешков, переславский рыболов (1562); Пешко, сын сольвычегодского крестьянина (1629); Пешко Гапонович, крестьянин Гомельского староства (1640).

https://www.analizfamilii.ru/Peshkov/proishozhdenie.html
Происхождение фамилии Пешков

Answer (score 0):

От Пешк**о** - уменьшительное к Петр.

К пешеходу или пехотинцу, ни реальному, ни шахматному отношения не имеет.

Аналогичного происхождения Песковы, тоже (в большинстве своем) не имеющие отношения к песку, Песк*о* - фонетический вариант того же имени. Хотя тут возможны варианты.

(+++)
Нашел в сети Федосюка. Память меня не обманула, там эта версия есть. 
https://www.e-reading.club/book.php?book=1010455

> ПЕШКОВ. Эту фамилию не надо связывать со словами «пеший», «пешка».
>   Хотя писалась она до революции через у («ять»), но происходит от Пешкó
>   – одной из весьма распространенных форм имени Петр, которое всегда
>   писалось через е. В повести «Детство» А. M. Горький пишет, что его
>   фамилию произносили Пешков, хотя сам он настаивал на ударении Пешкóв.

Comment: Скажите, пожалуйста, а есть ли тексты об этом диминутиве (или об этимологии самой фамилии)?

Comment: https://www.analizfamilii.ru/Peshkov/proishozhdenie.html

Comment: Людмила, информация из этого источника не выдерживает никакой критики.

Comment: @Aer У меня был бумажный Федосюк и еще одна замечательная книжица, вот не помню автора (по гуглу поищу, может вспомню). К сожалению, сейчас уже их нет. Если найдете Федосюка, то по памяти это там есть. А вообще эта версия достаточно известна и едва ли не общепризнанная среди серьезных исследователей.